# Mapping with D3: How to make D3.js tooltip appear over leaflet map on touch?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

**UPDATE: There seems to be a conflict with polyline for leaflet (the code has lines as in the example below the main code section. This is the link to the polyline leaflet library - https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator**

I cannot make the tooltip appear over a mapbox js map on mobile touch event for some reason. Otherwise everything works well on mobile browsers

The code works fine on non-mobile browsers and the tooltip with the information appear in the right place over the map.

I tried everything and it appears that the problem is that the mapbox or leaflet is interfering with d3.js on mobile. Any help greatly appreciated.

An example with tooltip which works on mobile, that I am basing my tooltip code on: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369

Here is the code which works on desktop:

A working example is also available here: http://ec2-54-193-23-111.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/G/Croatia/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js'></script>
<!--Leaflet / Mapbox -->
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator/master/leaflet.polylineDecorator.js'></script>
    <!-- JQuery -->

<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<!--Bootstrap,MDBootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
div.tooltip {   
    z-index: 99 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;            
    text-align: left;   
    left: 5vw;
    top: 5vh;                                   
    padding: 4px;   
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    color: white;
    background: #F9A13A;    
 /*   text-shadow: -1px 0 #2d2d2d, 0 1px #2d2d2d, 1px 0 #2d2d2d, 0 -1px #2d2d2d; */
    border: 5px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;       
    line-height: 150%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.mapbox-logo{
    display: none !important;
}
.leaflet-control-container 
{
  left: 2500px !important;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!--Div to hold the map. Inline styling is horrible I know, it's just for demo purpose... -->
<div id="map" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 0 !important"></div>
<script>
// Map details
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")   
    .style("z-index", 99)           
    .style("opacity", 0);
var options = {
  maxZoom: 16,
  minZoom: 2,
  zoomControl:false,
  attributionControl: false 
};
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RlbmluamEiLCJhIjoiSjg5eTMtcyJ9.g_O2emQF6X9RV69ibEsaIw';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', options).setView([42.572242,18.036804], 10)
L.control.zoom({
     position:'topright'
}).addTo(map);
d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/724e8bfe8c72654134799cc761ff5846/raw/0a66378bb4b0f9c2547ded49c9652147d0794d94/GJ_CMrally.json", function(error, d){
  d.features.forEach(function(d) {
            d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1],
                 d.geometry.coordinates[0])
    /*blue rings around circles:
map.addLayer(L.circle([d.geometry.coordinates[1], d.geometry.coordinates[0]], 30));*/
   })


// Append <svg> to #map
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg")
    .attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-animated")
    .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

// Append <g> to <svg>
var g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

// Append <circle> to <g>
var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(d.features)
    .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .style("fill", "#F9A13A")
    .style("opacity", ".5")
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", .9);  
                /* POPUP CONTENTS */ 
            div.html("<img src='"+d.properties.picurl+"'></ahref><br><br><h4 style='width: 380px; font-weight: 800; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: justify;'>"+ d.properties.name+"</h4><h5><p style='width: 380px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: justify;'>"+d.properties.description+"</h4></p><br><ahref='"+d.properties.picurl+"'>");
            })

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          div.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);


        });


function update() {
    translateSVG()
    circles.style("stroke", "gray")
    circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x; })
    circles.attr("cy", function(d) { return map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y; })
    circles.attr("r", 30)
}

// Adjust the circles when the map is moved
function translateSVG() {
    var viewBoxLeft = document.querySelector("svg.leaflet-zoom-animated").viewBox.animVal.x;
    var viewBoxTop = document.querySelector("svg.leaflet-zoom-animated").viewBox.animVal.y;
    // Reszing width and height incase of window resize
    svg.attr("width", window.innerWidth)
    svg.attr("height", window.innerHeight)
      // Adding the ViewBox attribute to our SVG to contain it
    svg.attr("viewBox", function() {
      return "" + viewBoxLeft + " " + viewBoxTop + " " + window.innerWidth + " " + window.innerHeight;
    });
    // Adding the style attribute to our SVG to transkate it
    svg.attr("style", function() {
      return "overflow: overlay;" + "transform: translate3d(" + viewBoxLeft + "px, " + viewBoxTop + "px, 0px);";
    });
}

map.on("moveend", update);
update();
});
</script>

     <!-- SCRIPTS -->


</body>
```

Polyline example (what the tooltip (.on("mouseover"... ? is conflicting with):

```
var arrow = L.polyline([[42.66425712817397,18.057164303027093],
                        [42.66211119633724,18.05321609135717],
                        [42.66084884945838,18.048409572802484],
                        [42.65933399937257,18.04222976323217],
                        [42.6579453543725,18.03330337163061],
                        [42.657187898574165,18.025406948290765],
                        [42.65731414184796,18.016137233935297],
                        [42.65807159610854,18.007897487841547],
                        [42.65933399937257,17.998627773486078],
                        [42.661101320884526,17.987984768114984],
                        [42.66387843890958,17.973050228320062],
                        [42.667917663793055,17.954167487332597],
                        [42.67422842424367,17.928933264920488],
                        [42.68394574212255,17.89769089431502],
                        [42.691390450870465,17.876061560818925],
                        [42.70123123868246,17.850655677029863],
                        [42.71207953045137,17.824563147732988],
                        [42.72305203610675,17.80018723286048],
                        [42.73087033885652,17.78542435444251],
                        [42.73641821397499,17.776154640087043],
                        [42.74297415380717,17.770318153270637],
                        [42.74763853506004,17.766541602977668],
                        [42.75129415611192,17.764653327831184],
                        [42.75595791133251,17.764138343700324],
                        [42.76087338149683,17.763795020946418],
                        [42.76490629655112,17.76448166645423],
                        [42.76944301218857,17.765683296092902],
                        [42.77108118895814,17.76671326435462]], {color: '#F9A13A', weight: 10, opacity: 0.8}).addTo(map);
```